# Select 'All' from drop down to retrieve all data

Tags: php

I have a list of countries in a dropdown, that when selected, filter the data down to posts within that country.

**The problem**

I have an 'All' option in the `select` input box, but not sure how to go about retrieving all the data using PDO.

The problem I am having is when it comes to binding the data using PDO. How can I configure it so it can accept an *all* value?

*[Note: data comes through `jquery AJAX`]*

**Code**

```
// HTML
<select name ="Country">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    /* the rest **/
</select>

// PHP
// {$conn->tbl_Table} is a reference to a key linking to a value table

$fetchQ = $conn->dbConn->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM {$conn->table_Table}
    WHERE
    Country :Country");

$fetchQ->execute(array(
    "Country"=>$_POST['Country']
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the simple `if` block

```
if(!empty($_POST['Country'] ) && $_POST['Country'] != "All"){
    $fetchQ = $conn->dbConn->prepare("
      SELECT *
      FROM {$conn->table_Table}
      WHERE
      Country :Country");

    $fetchQ->execute(array(
      "Country"=>$_POST['Country']
    ));
}else{
    $fetchQ =$conn->dbConn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM {$conn->table_Table}");
    $fetchQ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a query for ALL countries, just remove the country parameter from the query e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `country` = 'IDHERE';
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQLString = "SELECT * FROM ".$conn->table_Table;

$country_id = $_POST['Country']!="" ? 'WHERE country = '.$_POST['Country'] : '';


$fetchQ = $conn->dbConn->prepare($SQLString.$country_id)
```